# Jquery scroll script - menu to sit on top of section not inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code which I have had help with: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/2atkZ/embedded/result/

```
$(function () {

    var $select = $('#select');
    var $window = $(window);
    var isFixed = false;
    var init = $select.length ? $select.offset().top : 0;

    $window.scroll(function () {
        var currentScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        if (currentScrollTop > init && isFixed === false) {
            isFixed = true;
            $select.css({
                top: 0,
                position: 'fixed'
            });
            $('body').css('padding-top', $select.height());
        } else if (currentScrollTop <= init && isFixed === true) {
            isFixed = false;
            $select.css('position', 'relative');

            $('body').css('padding-top', 0);
        }
        //active state in menu
        $('.section').each(function(){
            var eleDistance = $(this).offset().top;
            if (currentScrollTop >= eleDistance) {
                var makeActive = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#select a').removeClass('active');
                $('#select a.' + makeActive).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });

    $(".nav").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var divId = $(this).attr('href');
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(divId).offset().top - $select.height()
        }, 500);
    });



});
```

Currently the seconds are defined when the yellow bar is fully inside that section. I want to make it so when I click on a section on the yellow bar to go to, the yellow bar sits on top of it, rather than inside it at the top. Is there a simple and elegant way of doing this, whilst still allowing the code to set the active state on the section which sits below it.

Comment: It's the same, the yellow bar has to be all the way inside the section for it to know its in that section

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2atkZ/2/ still not working correctly?

Comment: This should do what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/2atkZ/5/

Comment: I noticed in you original code you didn't have an animation-effect on the scroll. You want it or should it move to the section immediately?

Comment: Daniel that's actually pretty perfect! I modified it a tiny bit so it doesnt start with the active state on distribution. http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/2atkZ/6/

Comment: Ok, very good. Should I make that an answer?

Comment: But I dont suppose its possible to remove the active state on "posting" when you scroll up past the postin block? At the moment when you scroll all the way up posting stays active

Comment: Of course it's possible. Hold on a few minutes! :)

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2atkZ/7/ ?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, please add as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the work:

**HTML**

Instead of the anchors, use this:

```
<span data-sec="#posting" class="nav posting">posting</span>
<span data-sec="#distribution" class="nav distribution">distribution</span>
<span data-sec="#application" class="nav application">applicantions</span>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {

    var $select = $('#select');
    var $window = $(window);
    var isFixed = false;
    var init = $select.length ? $select.offset().top : 0;

    $window.scroll(function () {
        var currentScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        if (currentScrollTop > init && isFixed === false) {
            isFixed = true;
            $select.css({
                top: 0,
                position: 'fixed'
            });
            $('body').css('padding-top', $select.height());
        } else if (currentScrollTop <= init) {
            isFixed = false;
            $select.css('position', 'relative');
            $('#select span').removeClass('active');
            $('body').css('padding-top', 0);
        } 


        //active state in menu
        $('.section').each(function(){
            var eleDistance = $(this).offset().top;
            if (currentScrollTop >= eleDistance-$select.outerHeight()) {
                var makeActive = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#select span').removeClass('active');
                $('#select span.' + makeActive).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });

    $(".nav").click(function (e) {
        console.log('hej');
        var divId = $(this).data('sec'); console.log(divId);
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(divId).offset().top - $select.height()
        }, 500);
    });



});
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2atkZ/7/)